# How can I read the multiple passed parameters which I receive from a redirect from one page to another with JSF?

Tags: jsf

I pass `3` parameters when redirecting from `a.xhtml` to `b.xhtml`.

For each .xhtml page, I have also an aUiController.java and a bUiController.java correspondingly.

Let's assume that the `a.xhtml` contains only a `<p:commandButton>` which redirects to `b.xhtml` when clicked. See the code below:

```
<h:form>    
   <p:commandButton action="#{aUiController.goToPageB()}" value="Go to Page B" />
</h:form>
```

and the controller looks like this:

```
    import java.io.Serializable;

        @Named("aUiController")
        public class AUiController implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private long parameter1;
        private int parameter2;
        private String parameter3;

        /*
         *  Constructor
         */

        /*
         *  Getters & Setters
         */

         public String goToPageB(){
            this.parameter1 = 10;
            this.parameter2 = 7;
            this.parameter3 = "Hi!";
            return "b?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true&parameter1=" + getParameter1() + "&parameter2="
                + getParameter2() + "&parameter3=" + getParameter3();
         }
    }
```

On the `b.xhtml` I want to receive the data, that `a.xhtml` sends to me. The code in `b.xhtml` looks like the one below:

```
<h:head>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="parameter1"
            value="#{bUiController.parameter1}" />
        <f:viewParam name="parameter2"
            value="#{bUiController.parameter2}" />
        <f:viewParam name="parameter3"
            value="#{bUiController.parameter3}" />
    </f:metadata>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
       <p:outputLabel>#{bUiController.parameter1}</p:outputLabel>
       <p:outputLabel>#{bUiController.parameter2}</p:outputLabel>
       <p:outputLabel>#{bUiController.parameter3}</p:outputLabel>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

The UI controller for `b.xhtml` is the following:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

    @Named("bUiController")
    public class BUiController implements Serializable {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private long parameter1;
        private int parameter2;
        private String parameter3;

        /*
         *  Constructor
         */

        /*
         *  Getters & Setters
         */ 
    }
```

I am using `<f:metadata>` and `<f:viewParam>` in order to get the parameters,but unfortunately it does not work.

In case you know how to get the parameters read from JSF, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was talking with other developers and one of them told me the answer.

@MDD-MSCH: Thank you very much, for your help :)

The answer goes like this:

In order to send data from `a.xhtml` to `b.xhtml`, you need also to add the data in `a.xhtml` in `<f:param>`.

That means that the whole code is correct, but I need to add the parameters in `<f:param>`. When I do this, my `a.xhtml` will look like this:

```
<h:form>
   <f:param name="parameter1" value="#{aUiController.parameter1}" />
   <f:param name="parameter2" value="#{aUiController.parameter2}" />
   <f:param name="parameter3" value="#{aUiController.parameter3}" />
   <p:commandButton action="#{aUiController.goToPageB()}" value="Go to Page B" />
</h:form>
```

:)